# Is CIviCRM compatible with Concrete5?

Tags: webserver, evaluating-civicrm

Our website is built on the Concrete5 platform.  Is CiviCRM compatible with Concrete5?

Comment: How well abstracted is CiviCRM's CMS integration? Put simply, could a sufficiently-motivated "incredibly unlikely" person create the glue necessary to bind Concrete5 8.x with CiviCRM 5.x?

Comment: I would reckon that is feasible if indeed sufficiently-motivated. There used to be stand-alone version as well so my assumption is abstracted enough.....but never perfect :-)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it isn't as clearly documented as would be expected (seeing nothing on front page or /about or /get-started actually talks about CMS) but nevertheless CiviCRM has been built to work with Drupal, Joomla! and WordPress.
Hence the answer is somewhere between 'no' and 'incredibly unlikely' ;-)

Comment: This link  may clarify http://book.civicrm.org/user/website-integration/choosing-your-cms/